# Where is the night market in Ayutthaya (Hua Raw area)?

Tags: food-and-drink, thailand, locate-this

Wikimapia shows [this building](http://wikimapia.org/8117900/Hua-Raw-Night-Market) as a night market ("Hua Raw Night Market") in [Ayutthaya](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ayutthaya).
I went at night (7pm) last month, and it was not open.

However, an esplanade 200 meters away was a very busy outside night market, with ~50 stalls. Coordinates: 14.365882, 100.574783

Is it the new location of the night market?
Or was it a special occasion, and Hua Raw still functions as a night market?
Or are they both active night markets, and one just happened to be closed temporarily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location is correct but I think it opens from early morning and shuts around 4pm.

http://www.painaidii.com/business/134086/hua-ro-market-13000/lang/th/

Comment: But that would be a morning market, basically a regular market. Night markets are a different thing and usually in different locations to morning markets.